# PHP 7 - Unable to load dynamic library - curl.so

Tags: 14.04, php7

I am using phpunit to run unit tests and all is well and dandy.

That is until the test needs to use Curl.

At which point, I get this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/curl.so:
>   undefined symbol: zend_unset_property in Unknown on line 0

I am running php 7.

I have run

apt-get install php-curl, and apt-get install php7.0-curl, and both tell me I have the latest version of curl installed.

I've quite googled this to the max, and I'm totally stuck now.

PS - I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same issue.

Uninstall all versions of curl that you have currently installed. Purge them.

Then re install php7.0-curl, then try apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Doesn't work for me :(